# How to place a signature as image and name in the bottom right corner in latex?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I want to place a signature (as image), name and date in the bottom right corner of a page in latex. How can I do that ?

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{signature.png}
\newline \bfseries{My Name}
\newline \today
```

Something like this in the image.

[image]

Comment: Bottom right corner of the printable area of the sheet of paper (even if there's large gaps between the signature and the rest of the document), or in the bottom right corner of what's printed (small gap between the signature and the rest of the document, with a large space below)?

Comment: Looks like a letter. Do you already use a letter class?

Comment: Not a letter, trying to make a resume and I want to add a signature and name at the bottom. Bottom right corner of what is printed.

Comment: You can use the `graphicx`-package and perhaps create a new command like `\newcommand{\sig}{\parbox{3cm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sigfile}\\\centering
    My Name}}`  Than you only have to fiddle to get it in the place you want it.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south east)}]
\node[anchor=south east] (0,0) {\parbox{1.5in}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{pig}\\My name is pig}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page text area.south east)}]
\node[anchor=south east] (0,0)  {\parbox{1.5in}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{pig}\\My name is pig}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```